# Trigger by ElementName from other UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two UserControls(A,B) and I want to get `A_TextBox` Errors in UserControl A from the UserControl B. Is it possible?

```
 <Usercontrol x:Class="A" (...)>
     <TextBox x:name="A_TextBox (...)/>
 </Usercontrol>


<Usercontrol x:Class="B" (...)>
(...)
   <Controls:A/>

   <Button (...)>
      <Button.Style>
          <Style>
             <Style.Triggers>        
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=A_TextBox }" value="True">
                  <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" /> 
                </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
```

This code causes an error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=A_TextBox '. BindingExpression:Path=(0); DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

Comment: It is. You have to make them share a view model. At least for this particular binding.

Answer (score 1):

I've created two UserControls, A and B. A has a textbox whose Text is bound to an integer property of the UserControl, and A also has public readonly dependency property `HasError`. I get an error saying that `Validation.HasError` can't be data-bound, so I'm updating that property manually in a text-changed event handler. I created and included the `Integer` property so that I can type "xx" into the textbox and cause `Validation.HasError` to be true. Anything with working validation will work the same.

In the common parent, I bind A.HasError to B.IsEnabled, via a boolean-negation value converter. I could have written a trigger like yours as well. The advantage of this approach, in addition to the fact that it works, is that the two UserControls don't have to know about each others' internals, and neither one is dependent on the other. In addition, if you want to create nine of these pairs in a ListBox's ItemTemplate, you can do that without any problems.

A.xaml

```
<TextBox 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    TextChanged="IntegerTextBox_TextChanged"
    Text="{Binding Integer, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    />
```

A.xaml.cs

```
private void IntegerTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    HasError = Validation.GetHasError(sender as TextBox);
}

public bool HasError
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(HasErrorProperty); }
    protected set { SetValue(HasErrorPropertyKey, value); }
}

internal static readonly DependencyPropertyKey HasErrorPropertyKey =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(HasError), typeof(bool), typeof(A),
        new PropertyMetadata(false));

public static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorProperty = 
    HasErrorPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

public int Integer
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(IntegerProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IntegerProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IntegerProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Integer), typeof(int), typeof(A),
        new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NotConverter x:Key="Not" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:A 
            Integer="34" 
            x:Name="MyAInstance" 
            />
        <local:B
            IsEnabled="{Binding HasError, ElementName=MyAInstance, 
                        Converter={StaticResource Not}}"
            />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public class NotConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);
    }
}
```